# Error : 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 7526-7527: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, utf-8, load

I have a connection problem with direct download Bert model(company`s privacy policy) 
so, I downloaded BertTokenizer at https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/tokenization_bert.py

and got my model tokenizer`s txt file.
"bert-base-multilingual-cased": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-base-multilingual-cased-vocab.txt",

but When I import tokenizer model, get an error.
My code:

```
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("My BERT MODEL DIRECTORY", do_lower_case=False) 
tokenized_texts = [tokenizer.tokenize(sent) for sent in sentences]

print (sentences[0])
print (tokenized_texts[0])
```

Error Message
`'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 7526-7527: invalid continuation byte`

I trying to + encoding = 'utf-8', 'cp949' like this
`tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("My BERT MODEL DIRECTORY", encoding = 'uft-8', do_lower_case=False)`

but It doesn`t work.. 
Thank you for your comment in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string(s) can't be decoded, because it was truncated. Either you manually handle the error:

```
print (sentences[0].decode('utf-8', 'replace') # Replace the invalid characters with ?
print (tokenized_texts[0].decode('utf-8', 'ignore') # Completely remove the invalid characters
```

Or you register an handler globally:

```
import codecs

codecs.register_error('strict', codecs.lookup_error('surrogateescape'))
```

More info: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html